# How to find difference of timestamps in AWS cloudwatch log insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have cloudwatch log message "LogMonitor" from lambda log group which has all properties to apply filter. It have two timestamps, startTime and endTime and I want to find the difference (endTime - startTime) to know the response time of the lambda.

Query in cloudwatch log insights :

```
filter @message like /"LogMonitor"/
 | LogMonitor.Id as Id,
 LogMonitor.StartTime as startTime,
 LogMonitor.EndTime as endTime
by Id
```

[image]

What is the best approach to find difference of timestamps in query without using custom metrics?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to run something like this:

```
filter @message like /"LogMonitor"/
 | LogMonitor.Id as Id,
 LogMonitor.StartTime as startTime,
 LogMonitor.EndTime as endTime
| stats avg(endTime - startTime) by Id
```

Comment: That's what I did too but it did not work. Searching around but cannot find a solution.